# How to create a condition in javascript file with the controller in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, coffeescript

I am trying to expand the [like-twitter application tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/user-microposts#top) and include my first script (regardless of the tutorial).

I am trying to make a script that will only work when the user is signed in (I discovered that I need to make this rule because when the user is not signed in I get a script error).

the js file is called `static_pages.js.coffee` and contains code like this:

```
micropost =
  p: {
    ...
  }
  init: ->
    ...

$(document).ready ->
  micropost.init()
```

Since the code is relevant for micropost that appears **only** when user is signed in then I need some rule to notify me about that.

I can put in the main file `views/layout/application.html.erb` a script with the variable like this:

```
<head>
  <title><%=full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      var signed_in = <%= signed_in? =>;
  </script>

  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
</head>
```

but it doesn't look like the clean way, **my questions are:**

1. how do I do it?
2. Do I need to do it via controller? (I have no idea how...)
3. And also, I put the $(document).ready inside the static_pages.js.coffee - Should I put it in the main application.js since this is the call that invokes all function after dom is built?

Answer (score 0):

using this beauty: https://github.com/gazay/gon

include in the gem file:

```
gem 'gon'
```

Add to the application.html.erb (before the script):

```
  <%= include_gon %>
```

And inside any controller you can make this call:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    gon.signed_in = signed_in?
  end
```

and then you can just fetch this parameter from you js:

```
console.log(gon.signed_in)
```